# clarifications on the re.findall() method in python

Tags: python, regex, string, str-replace, replace

I wanted to strip a string of punctuation marks and I ended up using

```
re.findall(r"[\w]+|[^\s\w]", text)
```

It works fine and it does solve my problem. What I don't understand is the details within the parentheses and the whole *pattern* thing. What does `r"[\w]+|[^\s\w]"` really mean? I looked it up in the Python standard library and it says:

```
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.

I am not sure if I get this and the clarification sounds a little vague to me. Can anyone please tell me what a pattern in this context means and how exactly it is defined in the findall() method?

Comment: you want to learn about [regex](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break it down, `[]` creates a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).  You'll often see things like `[abc]` which will match `a`, `b` or `c`.  Conversely, you also might see `[^abc]` will will match anything that *isn't* `a`, `b` or `c`.  Finally, you'll also see character ranges:  `[a-cA-C]`.  This introduces two ranges and it will match any of `a`, `b`, `c`, `A`, `B`, `C`.

In this case, your character class contains special tokens.  `\w` and `\s`.  `\w` matches anything letter-like.  `\w` actually depends on your locale, but it is usually the same thing as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` matches anything in the ranges `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`.  `\s` is similar, but it matches anything that can be considered whitespace.

The `+` means that you can repeat the previous match 1 or more times.  so `[a]+` will match the entire string `aaaaaaaaaaa`.  In your case, you're matching alphanumeric characters that are next to each other.

the `|` is basically like "or".  match the stuff on the left, *or* match the stuff on the right if the left stuff doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` means Alphanumeric characters plus "_". And `\s` means Whitespace characters including " \t\r\n\v\f" and space character " ". So, `[\w]+|[^\s\w]` means a string which contains only words and "_".